# how to update label log in/log out from local.xml of customer.xml

Tags: layout, magento

I want only updating lable **Log in** to **Sign In** of customer.xml file. How can it possible from local.xml

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <!---<reference name="right">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login" before="-" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
    </reference>-->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
    <remove name="wishlist_sidebar"></remove>
    <remove name="reorder"></remove>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Comment: why do you want to do it from .xml? why not from translate.csv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

```
System->Configuration->Developer->Translate Inline->Enable for Frontend
```

**Set Yes**,save it.Open your frontend.You will see book like icon many places.Click that icon near login text,a pop up will appear.Change the login to sign and submit.Refresh the page and you can see the result.Dont forget to disable translate inline after you have made changes.

This is an another way of changing text.

Comment: *Thanks a lot!* I don't know the use of **Translate inline** Thanks again !

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the top links. Open app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv, and find the line that says

```
"Log In", "Log In"
```

Change it to:

```
"Log In", "Sign In"
```

You're done! Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I didn't know this use before your answer. Sorry for short comment! Thanks again for spending time.